# Hyper-v Virtual switch manager stuck at "applying changes"

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v

I am trying to set-up a Linux vm inside my windows 10 pro computer using the guide at ten forums here:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html

I have successfully turned on Hyper-v, however, when I go on to create a virtual switch from the virtual switch manager, it gets stuck at "applying changes". Just in case it was conflicting, I uninstalled virtualbox and rebooted, but it is still "applying changes" after two hours. How can I create virtual switches?

Comment: have you solved the problem in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable or install any interfering software, eg VPN SW or other virtualization SW that will install virtual devices.